# Identification of the crimp terminals

Tags: connector, wire-terminals

Here is an image of the connector and the crimp terminal I am trying to find out. The part code for the connector is 10112284-002LF from FCI.

[image]

Comment: Please provide dimensions

Answer (score 1):

The connector is from the [Amphenol (FCI) Pwr Profile I/O](https://cdn.amphenol-cs.com/media/wysiwyg/files/documentation/datasheet/power/pwr_pwrprofile.pdf) family. The photo shows the cable connector end which can be found under the P/N that you gave, [10112284-002LF](https://www.amphenol-cs.com/pwr-profile-10112284002lf.html). It doesn't appear that Amphenol sells just the housing alone or just the crimp terminal alone, you have to buy them both in a kit (which is what that P/N has -- a bottom and top cover and two crimps). Seems to be a pretty specialty part, since none of the major distributors have them. Might need to go directly to Amphenol on this one.